# Selenium WebDriver SubMenu click not working

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am not able to Click on SubMenu item using selenium webdriver using c#.
I am using IE9 and FireFox 13.
I have tried Action Builder but it does not work.
It gives an error saying element cannot be clicked.

```
    WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    IWebElement menu = Wait.Until((d) => webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("id1")));
    IWebElement menuOption = Wait.Until((d)=>webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ID2")));
            Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
            builder.MoveToElement(menu).Build().Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            //then click when menu option is visible
            menuOption.Click();
```

I have used even javascript :
js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('ID1')\").mouseover();"); // Mouse hove to main menu
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ID2")).Click();

Please give some solution to click on hidden elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Expected Conditions](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#expected-conditions) to wait for element being clickable after hovering above it (`Thread.sleep()` is almost always the bad choice. And 5 ms won't be enough.).

The [docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) for this class (`ExpectedConditions` in `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` namespace) are broken as I can see them now, but if you can follow the Java code in the link above, [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) are the Expected conditions for Java - it's really almost the same in C#, too.

Comment: Also, you haven't been very specific on the errors you get and how the page looks, so I took a guess. If that won't fix your problems, you might want to share more - how does the menu/submenu look like in HTML/CSS, how does it appear, what kind of error message are you getting etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the statement `Thread.sleep()`. You can try to click on the element after making sure that it is displayed.

After you get the WebElement you want to click on , check if it is displayed by using the `isDisplayed()` method within the ExpectedContition statement about which @Slanec is talking about in the above post.

By this you can make sure you will click on the element only after Wait.Until() returns **true**. i.e the `menuOption` is displayed.

I'm writing the code in java as I do not know C#. But I guess you can figure out what I'm trying to say -

```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver ) {


            return driver.findElement(By.Id("ID2")).isDisplayed();
        }
    });
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Hari it works fine for Firefox(it clicks the submenu) but for IE the browser Flicks any reason continuously.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what did you mean by flicks in IE browser.Can you tell me what exactly is happening when you run your code?